# Get all ValidationResults from Validator.TryValidateObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

**Question:** Is there another way to validate DataAnnotations than to use *Validator.TryValidateObject*

**Why:**
There is no way to specify to the Validator if you want it to validate `IValidatableObject`. That would be ok if it wouldn't be validating it only if the object is valid.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** Get a list of ALL validation results

If you look at the decompiled code from `Validator.TryValidateObject` drill down into `GetObjectValidationErrors`. You will get this (I've reformatted for easier reading)

```
private static IEnumerable<Validator.ValidationError> GetObjectValidationErrors(object instance, ValidationContext validationContext, bool validateAllProperties, bool breakOnFirstError)
{
  var list = new List<Validator.ValidationError>();
  list.AddRange(Validator.GetObjectPropertyValidationErrors(instance, validationContext, validateAllProperties, breakOnFirstError));
  if (list.Any())
    return list; //Doesn't continue if errors are found

  var validationAttributes = Validator._store.GetTypeValidationAttributes(validationContext);
  list.AddRange(Validator.GetValidationErrors(instance, validationContext, validationAttributes, breakOnFirstError));
  if (list.Any(()))
    return list; //Doesn't continue if errors are found

  var validatableObject = instance as IValidatableObject;
  if (validatableObject != null)
  {
    foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in Enumerable.Where<ValidationResult>(validatableObject.Validate(validationContext), (Func<ValidationResult, bool>) (r => r != ValidationResult.Success)))
      list.Add(new Validator.ValidationError((ValidationAttribute) null, instance, validationResult));
  }
  return list;
}
```

As you can see it is breaking as soon as it gets a set of validation results.

Comment: So to clarify, you are interested in seeing:  1) All Object Property validation errors, 2) All instance type validation errors, and 3) All custom validation errors?

Comment: Yes, I want to get all validation errors

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the ModelState property in the ControllerContext?  Say you have a controller action called Index accepting a posted model.  Within this method you can inspect the ModelState property and using a little LINQ magic, get all validation errors for you model.  This approach will not tell you where the validation errors came from.  Simply a text error message and possibly and exception.

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
            if( !ModelState.IsValid){
              var errors = this.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors);
            }

           return View();
}
```

Comment: I'm not in a controller.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all validation error within an implementation of IValidatableObject?

Comment: Yes but doing this cause a `StackOverflowException` because the `Validator` is calling IValidatableObject and IValidatableObject was calling Validator...

Comment: MVC will always process data annotation based validation first.  I don't think you can achieve what you want from within IValidatableObject